# How to create a Slide Out Menu after login view using XIB in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to create slide out menu.

I searched and found the example but all are for storyboard and which I found in `xib` are called on `AppDelegate` Class.
 I need to create a Slide out menu in `xib` which should be call after login.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

Comment: Set sliedout menu controller in storyboard as rootview and present loginview controllerif user not logged in

Comment: @Vinodh Any other example that is simple to implement.

Comment: https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController and lot are there try  to google  "side menu ios objective c"

Comment: @Muju did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The best example of side bar menu is [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). This library is easy to use and its easy to understand.

Comment: exactly it best but it is in Storyboard and not after log in.

Comment: no Sir you can also implement side bar after login. Suppose you have three controller but you want sw from second one so you can do it very easily. First push from one to second controller and then connect  sw to second controller so you can get sw in your second view controller.

Answer (score 1):

This below work for me well...try in your code.
_parentView is your custom slide out view and _rightView (UIButton )is used to dismiss these custom slide out view. you just initialize these two property

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *parentView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIButton *rightView;

    -(void)slideView
    {
        if(![_parentView isDescendantOfView:app.navController.view])
        {
             [self showMenu];
        }
        else
        {
            [self hideMenu];
        }
    }
    -(void)showMenu
    {
        int width=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;
        int height=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;

        _parentView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0-(width-70), 0, width-70, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height)];
        [_parentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightTextColor]];

        [app.navController.view addSubview:_parentView];

        _rightView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,80, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-80)];
        _rightView.alpha=0.7;
        [_rightView addTarget:self action:@selector(hideMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        if(_parentView.frame.origin.x <0)
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(showSideMenu) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        }


    }
    -(void)showSideMenu{

        if(_parentView.frame.origin.x <0)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
                    [self.view addSubview:_rightView];
                    _rightView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                }];

                CGRect frame =  _parentView.frame;
                frame.origin.x =0;
                _parentView.frame = frame;

                CGRect rightFrame=self.view.frame;
                rightFrame.origin.x=_parentView.frame.size.width;
                self.view.frame=rightFrame;

                CGRect fram1=app.navController.navigationBar.frame;
                fram1 .origin.x =_parentView.frame.size.width;
                app.navController.navigationBar.frame =fram1 ;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
        }
    }

    -(void)hideMenu
    {
        if(_parentView.frame.origin.x == 0)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                CGRect frame =  _parentView.frame;
                frame.origin.x=-_parentView.frame.size.width;
                _parentView.frame = frame;

                CGRect fram=self.view.frame;
                fram .origin.x=0;
                self.view.frame =fram ;

                CGRect fram1=app.navController.navigationBar.frame;
                fram1 .origin.x =0;
                app.navController.navigationBar.frame =fram1 ;


            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [_rightView removeFromSuperview];
                [_parentView removeFromSuperview];
            }];
        }
    }
```

Thank you...!!!

Comment: how can I add table view in that your parent view is transparant.

Answer (score 0):

PUSH FROM NORMAL VIEW CONTROLLER TO SW VIEW CONTROLLER

```
UIStoryboard*Storyboard=[AppDelegate storyBoardType];
SidebarViewController *sidebarmemu =(SidebarViewController*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SidebarController"];

tbTBC*tabbarController=(tbTBC*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbTBCId"];


SWRevealViewController *revealController;
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController;
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController;
frontNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tabbarController];
rearNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:sidebarmemu];
revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;
self.swcontroller =revealController;
self.view.window.rootViewController =self.swcontroller;
```

WITH THE HELP OF THIS CODE YOU CAN GET BOTH TAB BAR AS WELL AS SIDE BAR

Comment: @DishantRajpat I don't want this using Storyboard.